# Show snackbar over status bar

Tags: android

I would like to show a snackbar over the status bar and toolbar. Then, having this screen:

[image]

it should be displayed like:

[image]

Is this possible? I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think so. You can set the app to fullscreen so the status bar doesnt appear.
And to design your toolbar, you can use something like this if you are using AppCompatActivity :

```
private void configureToolbar(){
    // Get the toolbar view inside the activity layout
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    // Set the Toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

In your activity main, include the toolbar:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Create a layout for the bar and you´re good to go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Déclaration de notre Toolbar -->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"/>
```